# sbt command throws null pointer excepion

Tags: scala, sbt

I am new to scala and sbt and I want to run the sbt command but I get some Nullpointer exception, not sure why.

I have scala installed in the system:

> scala -version 
>   Scala code runner version 2.11.8 -- Copyright 2002-2016, LAMP/EPFL

Also if i try to check the sbt version works fine:

> sbt --version sbt launcher version 0.13.5

But when I just run sbt, I get an exception:

```
  info] Loading project definition from /home/workspace/myproject
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.util.regex.Matcher.getTextLength(java.base@9-internal/Matcher.java:1747)
        at java.util.regex.Matcher.reset(java.base@9-internal/Matcher.java:402)
        at java.util.regex.Matcher.<init>(java.base@9-internal/Matcher.java:244)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern.matcher(java.base@9-internal/Pattern.java:1108)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern.split(java.base@9-internal/Pattern.java:1221)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern.split(java.base@9-internal/Pattern.java:1288)
        at sbt.IO$.pathSplit(IO.scala:744)
        at sbt.IO$.parseClasspath(IO.scala:859)
        at sbt.compiler.CompilerArguments.extClasspath(CompilerArguments.scala:62)
        at sbt.compiler.MixedAnalyzingCompiler$.withBootclasspath(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:189)
        at sbt.compiler.MixedAnalyzingCompiler$.searchClasspathAndLookup(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:167)
        at sbt.compiler.MixedAnalyzingCompiler$.apply(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:177)
        at sbt.compiler.IC$.incrementalCompile(IncrementalCompiler.scala:138)
        at sbt.Compiler$.compile(Compiler.scala:128)
        at sbt.Compiler$.compile(Compiler.scala:114)
        at sbt.Defaults$.sbt$Defaults$$compileIncrementalTaskImpl(Defaults.scala:814)
        at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$compileIncrementalTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:805)
        at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$compileIncrementalTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:803)
        at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
        at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
        at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:63)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
        at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
        at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:235)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
        at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:159)
        at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:28)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(java.base@9-internal/FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(java.base@9-internal/Executors.java:514)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(java.base@9-internal/FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.base@9-internal/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1158)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(java.base@9-internal/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:632)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@9-internal/Thread.java:804)
    [error] (compile:compileIncremental) java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: add you sbt file to post

Comment: @Vasilisck Sorry I don't understand what you mean? What is the sbt file? I am very new first time using sbt

Comment: Where do you run the sbt command? inside a project ? if so, what is inside that project?

Comment: Perhaps you should try it with Java 8. Since Java 9 is not released yet, I doubt sbt is ever tested on it.

Comment: @sfrj did you resolve this? If so, do you mind sharing what you did, please?

Comment: @EmilyChen Hi I am sorry, I think I did solve it some months back but I am unsure how I did it :( I didn't use Scala much, not sure. If I use it again soon and come across with it again I will update the question.

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace

```
Loading project definition from /home/workspace/myproject
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.util.regex.Matcher.getTextLength(java.base@9-internal/Matcher.java:1747)
        at java.util.regex.Matcher.reset(java.base@9-internal/Matcher.java:402)
        at java.util.regex.Matcher.<init>(java.base@9-internal/Matcher.java:244)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern.matcher(java.base@9-internal/Pattern.java:1108)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern.split(java.base@9-internal/Pattern.java:1221)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern.split(java.base@9-internal/Pattern.java:1288)
```

indicates that you tried running sbt 0.13.5 under JDK 9, which at the time was not supported. As suggested by thirstycrow in comment, at the recommended course of action is to use JDK 8.

If you're using JDK 9 or 10, sbt 1.1.6 or later should work better using the latest launch script.